# Electromyography: is this interference from the heart/how to remove it?

Tags: matlab, noise, filtering

I'm using electromyography to evaluate the activity of lumbar erector spinae at various levels of effort.
For this I also intend to sample the activity at complete rest (in prone lying). In my first few attempts I noticed regulary occuring spikes in the raw signal.
[image: emg of erector spinae]
could this be interference from the heart beat or is it something else?

In [another question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22278/how-to-remove-heart-beats-interference-from-pectoralis-major-electromyogram/22680#22680) I found some advice on how to filter these artifacts out.
But since emg-sampling and signal processing are both new to me I wonder

*if there are methods easier to understand and apply than independent component analysis?*

In the question above it is mentioned that it's possible to record the heart signal simultaneously and remove it subsequently from the emg-signal.

*Is it possible to record the signal of the heart in prone lying and with a normal EMG-system?*

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KkcESU8DuUYWRZZmhwQmpOWFk/view?usp=sharing) is the data from the graph. I sampled it at 2000Hz.

Comment: The QRS complex is prominent and if you look closely the ST segment is there as well. I would say yes, the EKG.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even see the ST segment until you mentioned it. Thanks for your opinion